# Jenkins returns (403) Forbidden when posting delete request to API

Tags: c#, api, post, jenkins

I am trying to delete a Jenkins job using a C# script.
When I run the code, it actually works. The job is deleted. However, Jenkins still returns a 403 error. Am I doing something wrong?

This is my code:

```
String credentials = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsUser"] + ":" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsKey"];
String authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
try
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authorization;
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsDeleteJobUrl"], "POST", "");
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
}
catch(WebException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
    throw e;
}
```

the url I use is [My Jenkins url]/job/{0}/doDelete

I also tried using HttpWebRequest with the same result. Hope someone knows the answer.

**[Edit]** note that when I use Postman to do the same request, it goes through all right, redirecting to the Jenkins main page with a return code 200.

This is the Postman call:

```
POST /job/[jobname]/doDelete HTTP/1.1
Host: [my jenkins url]
Authorization: Basic [my auth hash]
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: Are you using CSRF Protection in Jenkins? If so, you have to include a CSRF Protection token in request.  You can turn off the "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" in Jenkins and see if it still happens.

Comment: No, I haven't turned that on (yet), so that can't be it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that, when you delete a Jenkins job using the doDelete url, you get redirected to your Jenkins homepage. Since you do this programatically, Jenkins does not recognize a user session (even though your original request contained an Authorization header), resulting in a forbidden code.

As a work-around, I did the following:

```
try {
    string credentials = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsUser"] + ":" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsKey"];
    string authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authorization;
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsDeleteJobUrl"], jobName), "POST", "");
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    // ignore the 403 error for now
    HttpWebResponse errorResponse = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    if(errorResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

// if the job no longer exists, it is proof that the request went through
if(!JenkinsHelper.GetJenkinsJobs().Contains(jobName))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Job successfully deleted.");
    return true;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Could not delete job.");
    return false;
}
```

with this helper function, in which JenkinsJobListUrl = [MyJenkinsUrl]/api/xml?xpath=hudson/job/name&wrapper=jobs

```
public static List<string> GetJenkinsJobs()
{
    try
    {
        string credentials = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsUser"] + ":" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsKey"];
        string authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authorization;
            string HtmlResult = wc.DownloadString(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jenkinsJobListUrl"]));
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(HtmlResult);
            return doc.Root.Elements("name").Select(element => element.Value).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not retreive Jenkins job list");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I know it isn't pretty, but for lack of a better solution this gets the job done.

Hope this helps people who have been struggling with this too. If you find a better solution, please let me know.